# BackgroundGeolocation not working in background but in foreground fire why?

Tags: geolocation, ionic3

Team i have implemented the tracking functionality in our app and using BackgroundGeolocation but its not working in the background below we have mentioned scenario:

**Case 1:**

BackgroundGeolocation is fire only 1 time if i am foreground not in background below links we have used for BackgroundGeolocation :

> https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-background-geolocation-to-an-ionic-2-application/
>
> https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-3-get-background-device-location-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-geolocation-plugins/

i have tried above links but i got same result for me.i really stuck location issues in ionic3 as well ionic community is not supported for any query.

```js
   loadLocation(){
   // foreground Tracking
   var self = this;
          //get user currentLocation and update user location after move move    
      self.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {

        //self.subscription = self.watch.subscribe((position) => {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        console.log('lat fire1.....', +position.coords.latitude);
        console.log('long fire.....', +position.coords.longitude);

        //set center to map and set zoom....
        self.map.setCenter(latLng);
        self.map.setZoom(16);

        //updateDriverLocation for get driver updated location...
        self.updateDriverLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        //moveMarker for ,move marker......
        self.moveMarker(position);
      }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
      });

      // Background Tracking
      let config = {
        desiredAccuracy: 0,
        stationaryRadius: 20,
        distanceFilter: 10, 
        debug: true,
        interval: 2000 
      };

      this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) => {
        alert('dddddd');
        console.log('BackgroundGeolocation:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);
            //updateDriverLocation for get driver updated location...
          self.updateDriverLocation(location.latitude,location.longitude);
          self.moveMarker(location);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
      this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
   }
```

I tried each and everything but nothing worked please team help me.

Comment: you mean not working after the exit app?

Comment: No sir..if am in background function is not fire like.this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) this function is not fire,it will fire only 1time if am in forground 
not fire in the background pleasee help me how to fix?